# Why Google Chrome is a affecting to my CSS @media-queries?

Tags: android, html, css, media-queries

I know that the question may cause confusing, but I am having problems with my `CSS @media queries`, specially with the screen orientation.

I have this on the `<head>` of my page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1">
```

And a simple `CSS @media queries` that changes a style of an element **when the screen is portrait**:

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {

        #login_container {
            width: 60%;
        }
    }
```

So the problem is when I press on an `<input type="text">`, [**It is happening to me only on Android devices**] and when the keyboard is opened for write with it, the browser recognizes my screen as landscape so my **`CSS @media queries` is applying styles for landscape screens**.

But the weird thing about everything is that it only happens when the `<input>` is `type="text"` or `type="password"`, if not, the problem doesn´t happens.

I suppose that it is happening becouse when the keyboard is opened it resizes the browser window to other size, that (on some devices) is recognized as landscape, becouse window width is greater than window height.

I have been searching for a while on Google to find a solution, but I am unable to know how to fix it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment yet, but have you tried to set a `@media query` with `px` instead of `portrait / landscape` ?

I am pretty sure that your problem is, as you said, the size of your screen device, when the keyborad is  opened, result as a calculation of with / height it becomes as portrait for your browser's point of view...

I asume it doesn't happen the same on a bigger screen smarthphones nor tablets, nevermind which browser is used. At least you could give it a chance and try it to clarify your doubt :)